# Conditional Construct Syntax Issue - Square or Round Brackets

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm studying basic Bash scripting on a Debian System 8.6. I've read an example I found on a book that shows how to build a conditional construct. I let you it below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Filname: CondConst.sh

if [$UID -ne 0]; then
        echo "Non root User."
else
        echo "Root User."
fi
```

When I run the script containing this code I get the following error message and result:

```
[1000: command not found
Root User.
```

I've tried to modify the code in many ways (using quotes and spaces), but I could not understand how to use square brackets syntax for the comparision. I worked out the issue by using a different syntax, that I show you below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Filname: CondConst.sh

if (($UID!=0)); then
        echo "Non root User."
else
        echo "Root User."
fi
```

Can anyone explain me, if possible, the reason why I can not use square brackets?

Thank you, really, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because you are not typing a space after `[` so it is see it as a one command `[1000`, so just type space:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Filname: CondConst.sh

if [ $UID -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Non root User."
else
        echo "Root User."
fi
```

Comment: Thank you also for having clarified to me why the System shows me [1000.